# about older android versions on google market

Tags: java, android

I have developed my app in android 2.2, and put it on google market (munspel-appen).
I could see in the statistics that 4% are using android version 2.1 i dont have access to such device, so I wonder if my app will still work on that older version device if downloaded from market too or is it only working from 2.2 and up? How can one tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration of your app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.munspel.munspelappen) seems to limit the app to devices with 2.2 and higher.

Users with a lower OS Version then 2.2. can not download your app from google market.

I would test your App in an Android 2.1 Emulator and if it works there change the minSDK for your app to 2.1 and upload an update to the market. In that way your app will be available to as much users as possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can try in the android emulator in eclipse for example

Answer (score 1):

Your application may work for 2.1 version provided that your application is compatible with `API Level 7`. 
Well you can specify `android:minSdkVersion=8` in AndroidManifest, (from document)The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute, You can try running your application on Emulator running 2.1 version. read more http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#uses

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay, there are several companies specializing in testing Android apps on physical devices. Examples:

- http://duarlander.ning.com
- http://www.perfectomobile.com

I think there's a lot more in google.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Market should use the `minSdkVersion` in your Manifest to filter the apps when searched.

To test, you can use an emulator of version 2.1 and see whether it works.

Most probably most of the code will work except those new in 2.2.